# How does Incoming Email work in SharePoint?

Tags: incoming-email

Lets say, SMTP is configured on the server - server01.test.com and Incoming Email is enabled and SharePoint 2010 uses the SMTP server.

However the Email ID (ex., mydocs@test.com) is nowhere exists in SharePoint and user sends a mail to the Email ID.

I could see that Email is put on Drop folder on the SMTP server however howlong it will be kept on the drop folder? and when it will be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you install SMTP on IIS, Drop box will be created automatically.

Open IIS manager -> Default SMTP virtual Server -> Domains -> MOSSserver.domain.com -> Properties.

Check the drop directory location, default location would be "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop" where all the emails will be stored till Sharepoint timer service pick it up.  Sharepoint timer service will check this folder every 5 minutes (default). The timer job that picks up mail runs about every 5 minutes or so, so you should not see the email sit there for long

"Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail" service will pick's up the emails from the drop folders and sends to the required location using the `X-Sender` and `X-Receiver` headers in your emails, these headers is automatically added if you use the SMTP service in Windows.